# Creating new numpy array from existing array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have existing numpy array (uint8) which looks like this:

(Values are 8bit, i am interested only in last 3 of them)

```
[
    [ 00000AAA, 00000BBB, 00000CCC ],
    [ 00000FFF, 00000EEE, 00000DDD ],
    [ 00000GGG, 00000HHH, 00000III ],
    [ 00000LLL, 00000KKK, 00000JJJ ]
]
```

And in the end I would like to have data in this form:

```
[01AAABBB, 01CCCDDD 01EEEFFF, 01GGGHHH, 01IIIJJJ, 01KKKLLL]
```

Also, every second row is reversed.

Currently i have a long and winding code whitch iterates over the original list row-by-row and cell-by-cell, shifts and adds data, but that is not efficient enough.

Are there any good and efficinet methods solving that problem?

Comment: Does the input array always have shape (4, 3)?

Comment: No, but the actual problem has always shape (100,300)

Comment: To be sure: you want new array where each element is a combination of one odd element and 1000* an even element, plus 01000000; where the order of parsing is "up-and-down" through the original array?

Comment: Maybe, you should consider to write a library in C/Fortran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using Numpy built-in commands and vector style indexing, so it's pretty compact (and should be quicker than iterating):

**Updated with suggestions from comments**

```python
# Reverse direction of every second row
unsnaked_array       = np.array(inp_array)
unsnaked_array[1::2] = inp_array[1::2, ::-1]

# Change to one long array
unsnaked_array = unsnaked_array.ravel()
unsnaked_array &= 0x7    # Extra safety :)    

# Sum every pair of elements (with first element rolled) and add required bit
result_array = (unsnaked_array[::2]<<3) + unsnaked_array[1::2] + (1<<6)
```

Comment: Nice and simple, +1. The odd row reversal can be done more efficiently as `arr[1::2] = arr[1::2, ::-1]`. I would probably have thrown an `arr &= 0x7` to make sure that onlt the 3 LSB were used, but that may be being too cautious.

Comment: For some reason I can't the in-place reverse to work, the last element of each reversed row is set to the first… e.g.for an input of `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` I get `[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 6]]`. Weird.

Comment: The reversal happens in-place, so you overwrite the data as the reverse takes place. If you use the same syntax into a different array, it will work.

Comment: Thank you! that solved the problem!
The first in pairs should be shifted
(unsnaked_array[::2]<<3) + unsnaked_array[1::2]

I just replaced 20 lines of ugly code with 5